$\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$ where $0$ is isolated in the domain of $f$?
I just want a confirmation about this: consider $f: \{0\} \cup (2, 3) \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as $f(x) = x^2$.
Is it true that $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$ doesn't exist? I ask this because I have studied that limits at a certain point of the domain are possible iff that point is a limit point for the domain of the function. Here $0$ is an isolated point, hence it cannot be a limit point.
If all of this is true, why can't we perform the limit, but still we can evaluate $f(0) = 0$?
It's maybe a stupid question, but this actually relates to the fact that $f$ is not continuous at $x = 0$, and indeed if we studied $f(0) = \lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$ we would find it's impossible.
Right?

The limit does not make sense as $0$ is not an accumulation point of the domain. The theorem relating continuity and the limit is only true for accumulation points. In fact, every function is continuous at an isolated point, as is the case here.

@JulioPuerta Thank you! Of course when I say "limit point" I meant "accumulation point" (I know they are synonyms). So if I cannot use the theorem you cited, how would I prove continuity here? I know an answer may be via $\epsilon-\delta$, but if possible I wanted to avoid it...
I was thinking more of something like $$|f(x) - f(0)| = x^2$$ which goes to $0$ as $x \to 0$ (??)

Again, you cannot use sequences/limits, the point is isolated.

That function is continuous at $0$. For every $\varepsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(0)|<\varepsilon\,$ whenever $\,x\,$ is in the domain and $|x-0| < \delta$. That the only $x$ for which that is true when $\delta < 1$ makes the assertion true for any value you choose for $f(0)$.
Thus the function is continuous if you redefine its value at $0$ to be $1001$ or any other number although the algebraic formula you used on $(2,3)$ will no longer work at $0$.
As @JulioPuerta
comments, every function is continuous at isolated points in its domain.

Can I say $|f(x) - f(0)| = x^2$ which is basically the distance in $\mathbb{R}$ between $x^2$ (generic point) and the origin, and this distance goes to $0$ as $x \to 0$, hence it holds true the continuity? Or is this a weak method?

In tricky edge case situations like this you don't want to use phrases like "goes to" or expressions with arrows. You have to go back to the formal definition. In ordinary situations the casual phrasing can be rewritten rigorously so is OK (in most contexts).

We can't really let $x\to 0$. This typically means $x$ gets closer and closer to $0$ without ever touching it.

@EthanBolker Thank you! That was clear. Thank you both. Oh, a random question just popped out: can I say that the function is differentiable at $x = 0$? Since I cannot use the definition, how would I proceed to prove or disprove?

Seem vacuously true as well. And the derivative can be assigned any value you like!

Perhaps I cannot. Differentiability is not defined at isolated points I guess, because at isolated points I cannot perform things like $f(0 + h)$ and so on...

Differentiability at a point $c$ indeed is usually defined when the function is defined on an open interval $(a,b)$ containing $c$. If you take that away, you don't have a very interesting notion of derivative any more.

@Heidegger Right. The definition of the derivative makes no sense at an isolated point. The definition of continuity does, and is vacuously satisfied.

@Heidegger: Just a remark: It's often said that $f$ is continuous at the point $a \in D_f$ if and only if $f(x) \to f(a)$ as $x \to a$. But that's not the whole truth; the correct statement is that $f$ is continuous at $a$ iff $f(x) \to f(a)$ (which requires $a$ to be a limit point of $D_f$) or $a$ is an isolated point of $D_f$.

@HansLundmark Thank you! I would love if notes and books were that rigorous as you and other people I found over here...

@Heidegger Yes and no about rigor. Too much too soon confuses learners. Asking for rigor here when you are puzzled is probably better than having to struggle when the concept is new.

To say that $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=L$ is to say that
$$\forall \varepsilon>0, \exists \delta>0, \forall x\in \lbrace 0\rbrace\cup(2,3),\ 0<|x|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-L|<\varepsilon.$$
This can be proven vacuously for any value of $L$ you like. Let $\varepsilon>0$ and take $\delta=1$. Then it is vacuously true that for every $x\in \lbrace 0\rbrace\cup(2,3)$ such that $0<|x|<\delta$ (since there are no such $x$ values), we would have $|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$.
This is indeed why you will see the fine-print of the particular $x$ value needing to be a limit point when you have more general domains. The concept of a limit at non-limit-points just isn't useful.
